# How to move second slider on modified range slider

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I am using the modified code for a Range Slider from [here](http://ernienotes.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/creating-a-java-swing-range-slider/). It mostly uses the standard Java slider code.

In a comment further down the page, [here](https://ernienotes.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/creating-a-java-swing-range-slider/#comment-17), B.Oytun Peksal provides code for one thumb to push the other, but he only provided code for the UpperThumb.

Despite numerous attempts, I cannot figure out the code for the lower thumb and he has not responded to my request. Can anyone figure out what the code for the other thumb should be? My Java is OK but obviously not up to this. Thanks in advance.

This is a copy of the code he provided:

```
            case JSlider.HORIZONTAL:

                int halfThumbWidth = thumbRect.width / 2;
                int thumbRight = currentMouseX - offset;
                int trackLeft = trackRect.x - halfThumbWidth;
                int trackRight = trackRect.x + (trackRect.width - 1);
                int hMin = (int) thumbRect.getCenterX();
                // Apply bounds to thumb position.
                thumbRight = Math.max(thumbRight, trackLeft);
                thumbRight = Math.min(thumbRight, trackRight);
                hMin = hMin - halfThumbWidth;
                if (thumbRight >= hMin)
                {
                    setUpperThumbLocation(thumbRight, upperThumbRect.y);
                    // Update slider extent.
                    thumbMiddle = thumbRight + halfThumbWidth;
                    slider.setExtent(valueForXPosition(thumbMiddle) - slider.getValue());
                }
                else
                {
                    thumbMiddle = thumbRight + halfThumbWidth;
                    setThumbLocation(thumbRight, thumbRect.y);
                    slider.setValue(valueForXPosition(thumbMiddle));
                    setUpperThumbLocation(thumbRight, upperThumbRect.y);
                    slider.setExtent(valueForXPosition(thumbMiddle) - slider.getValue());
                }
                break;

    default:
        return;
}
```

Comment: search here for BoundedRangeModel & JSlider, there must be something for two or more JSliders

Comment: Thanks mKorbel, will take a look...